# Where can I find this particular problem (which is popular and historical) regarding Maxwell's laws of electromagnetism?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, history, maxwell-equations

Where can I find the problem talked about in the following paragraph regrading Maxwell's laws of electromagnetism -

> Every time Maxwell rearranged his equations to make the speed of light the subject and plugged in the numbers he got a very strange result. The speed of light always came out the same, regardless of the speed of the light source. This result seemed absurd! It's common sense that anything cast from a moving body will have a speed that's calculated from both the moving body and the object.

as seen on [here](http://www.emc2-explained.info/The-Constant-Speed-of-Light) in the paragraph titled as 'An impossible Result ?

Comment: [There's a description of the calculation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Vacuum_equations.2C_electromagnetic_waves_and_speed_of_light)

Answer (score -2):

That the speed of light is independent of the speed of the light source was a tenet of the ether theory - it wasn't Maxwell's discovery. In 1887 (prior to FitzGerald and Lorentz advancing the ad hoc length contraction hypothesis) the Michelson-Morley experiment UNEQUIVOCALLY confirmed the variable speed of light predicted by Newton's emission theory of light and refuted the constant (independent of the speed of the light source) speed of light predicted by the ether theory and later adopted by Einstein as his special relativity's second postulate:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emission_theory 
 "Emission theory, also called emitter theory or ballistic theory of light, was a competing theory for the special theory of relativity, explaining the results of the Michelson–Morley experiment of 1887. [...] The name most often associated with emission theory is Isaac Newton. In his corpuscular theory Newton visualized light "corpuscles" being thrown off from hot bodies at a nominal speed of c with respect to the emitting object, and obeying the usual laws of Newtonian mechanics, and we then expect light to be moving towards us with a speed that is offset by the speed of the distant emitter (c ± v)."

http://books.google.com/books?id=JokgnS1JtmMC 
 Banesh Hoffmann, Relativity and Its Roots, p.92: "There are various remarks to be made about this second principle. For instance, if it is so obvious, how could it turn out to be part of a revolution - especially when the first principle is also a natural one? Moreover, if light consists of particles, as Einstein had suggested in his paper submitted just thirteen weeks before this one, the second principle seems absurd: A stone thrown from a speeding train can do far more damage than one thrown from a train at rest; the speed of the particle is not independent of the motion of the object emitting it. And if we take light to consist of particles and assume that these particles obey Newton's laws, they will conform to Newtonian relativity and thus automatically account for the null result of the Michelson-Morley experiment without recourse to contracting lengths, local time, or Lorentz transformations. Yet, as we have seen, Einstein resisted the temptation to account for the null result in terms of particles of light and simple, familiar Newtonian ideas, and introduced as his second postulate something that was more or less obvious when thought of in terms of waves in an ether. If it was so obvious, though, why did he need to state it as a principle? Because, having taken from the idea of light waves in the ether the one aspect that he needed, he declared early in his paper, to quote his own words, that "the introduction of a 'luminiferous ether' will prove to be superfluous."

Comment: While that's an interesting answer (and worth reading, I'm not suggesting you delete it), it doesn't answer the specific question.  The question was "how did Maxwell's equations come up with this result", not who came up it.

Comment: There seems to be rather a lot of revisionist history going on here. Nineteenth century physics was perfectly OK with a wave equation implying a speed for a wave—indeed they expected it—but that speed was *as measured relative the medium*. They hadn't detected the medium of EM waves but they still named it: aether. Just as ripples on a pond move faster or slower when measured by an observer in motion relative the water, they expected EM wave to more faster or slower relative an observer in motion relative the aether. That's what MM was trying to detect.

Comment: "Just as ripples on a pond move faster or slower when measured by an observer in motion relative the water, they expected EM wave to more faster or slower relative an observer in motion relative the aether. That's what MM was trying to detect."  No. The result they expected was calculated on the assumption that the speed of light is independent of the speed of the light SOURCE. The experiment showed a different (null) result, which meant that the assumption was false - the speed of light does depend on the speed of the light source.

Comment: @PentchoValev Except it doesn't.

Comment: Classically the speed of a wave in a medium is constant relative that medium and the observed frequency of the wave depends on the motion of the source relative the medium and also on the motion of the observer relative the medium. Relativistically, light exhibits a constant speed to all observers and to all sources, and it's shift of frequency is dependent on the *difference* in the motion of the source and observer but not independently on either one reltive the (apparently non-existent) medium.